# Return all args used in query_posts for use in another WP_Query

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

I'd like to grab all the args that were passed to the original query_posts (main loop) and be able to modify them for use in another secondary loop. For example, if the main loop passed a whole bunch of args, I'd like to grab them all, modify one of the args, say 'post_type' and change it to another type and then re-run the query in a secondary loop.

Obviously I can setup the secondary loop already and pass my own arguments to it, but I'd like to use the very same args that were passed in the main loop. So I need some function or method to return all the args that were passed in the main loop, anyone know?

Comment: Why don't you just use `pre_get_posts` to alter the query variables just before the main query is run. From what I understand, you want to altr the main query by creating a secondary one. This will slow your page down and increase db calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments are stored in the global `$wp_query` variable. You can retrieve them with `$wp_query->query_vars`. So for your case you could do something like this...

```
//Store the query vars in a variable
$query_vars = $wp_query->query_vars;

//Edit the tag_id
$query_vars['post_type'] = 'another-type';

//create new wp_query
$new_query = new WP_Query($query_vars);
```

Hope that helps

Dan